# 34.12.1: PRACTICE: Manipulate text files

Tags: python, file

I'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting 2 extra lines in my output.  Can someone figure this out for me please?

#open, write, and read text file (e.g., "WordTextFile1.txt") using open(), write(), read()

```
file_name = (input())#store name of the file

with open(file_name,'r') as f: 
    word1 = str(f.read())
    word2 = str(f.read())
    word3 = str(f.read())
    
#solution accepts file input to insert sentence composed of file content into text file on a new line

f = open(file_name,"r")
   
lines = f.read().splitlines()
lines=' '.join(lines)
lines = lines.replace('\n', '')

f.close();#close the file

#solution outputs the text file contents including the new sentence

print(f"{word1}\n{word2}\n{word3}\n{lines}")
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f34fs.png)

Comment: `.read()` fetches the entire file contents.  So after you call `.read()` the first time, there isn't anything left to read, and thus `word2` and `word3` will be blank strings.

Comment: Maybe you meant to call `.readline()`, which reads a single line, instead of `.read()`, which reads everything.

Comment: No. the output is returning all three words but including 2 extra lines before the final line.  See the output image I attached.

Comment: Yes, those two extra blank lines are because you print `{word2}\n` and `{word3}\n`.  Those strings are blank, and thus the output is just two extra blank lines.  `word1` contains the entire file contents, `student\nreads\nbook\n`.

Comment: So, I changed it to this:    words = [f.read() for _ in range(3)]  but the output is still the same.

Comment: That isn't really a change at all.  You're still calling `.read()` three times.  The first call reads _everything_ in the file, and the second and third calls return blank strings because there is nothing left to read.  The only thing you changed is that you have a list with three items, instead of three separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Gordon says in the comments, read() reads the entire file. So you probably want readline() instead:

```
file_name = input()  # store name of the file

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    word1 = str(f.readline()).strip()  # Read first line of the file, removing whitespace (e.g. \n)
    word2 = str(f.readline()).strip()  # Read second line of the file, removing whitespace (e.g. \n)
    word3 = str(f.readline()).strip()  # Read third line of the file, removing whitespace (e.g. \n)

f = open(file_name, "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
lines = ' '.join(lines)
# lines = lines.replace('\n', '')  # You don't need this line, as splitlines() has already done this for you
f.close()  # close the file

print(f"{word1}\n{word2}\n{word3}\n{lines}")
```